# Let's say I have an array of characters (a string ) and I want to count how many time each character appears. However there should be no if

Tags: java, c++, arrays, character-encoding

So the way I approach this problem was to create a second array of int of size 26  called  count to represent how many time each letter appear, thus

```
from = 0 Iteration < letters.length(); iteration ++;
  count[letter.charAt(i)-97]++;   
                                    //Subtract 97 because it is the ASCII        
                                  //code for a so that a is 0 b is 1...
```

Assume that every character is lower case.
This is my algorithm so far and it work perfectly fine
but only if the array of characters does not have any 
space. Because space = 32 and 32-97 equal a negative number.

Now my plan was to make count 1 more bigger an store space there. That would be 27. So it would look something like this. a = 97 = 0
                                             b = 98 = 1
                                             c = 99 = 2
                                             ...
                                             space = 27
I been trying since this morning to make it work. But I haven't been able to.
I would really appreciate the help. And thank you in advance.

Comment: You might want to use [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) instead. The key can be the character, the value can be the count of that character. You could have a count of each character, not just each letter.

Comment: C++ and Java are completely different languages. Pick one when asking questions here.

Comment: @Steve that would make my array too big.

Comment: @NeilButterworth language is not the problem I can program in either of those.

Comment: It's a problem for us trying to provide a solution though. And our time is much more valuable than yours.

Comment: @Steve I'm only allow to use basic functions to solve this problem.Meaning nothing like LinkList or a function to trim the white space.

Comment: @NeilButterworth you can solve this problem in either of those languages (: thats why (;

Comment: I just answered a similar question.  In summary:  sort the array.  Count the number of contiguous slots that have the same value.  In other words, if [x] is equal to [x+1], increment your counter.

Comment: In C++, you can use character literals, such as `'A'`, instead of their ASCII equivalent.  A lot more portable.

Answer (score 0):

To start with you don't have 26 characters, you have 27; as the space character is allowed.

```
char letter = 0;
    for ( int i =0; i < len; i++ )
    {
        letter = arraySource[i];
        switch( letter )
        {
            case ' ':
                break;
            default:
                count[ letter - 'a' ]++;
                break;
         }
    }
```

Using 97 is going to lead you to trouble.

Using C++ you would use String::length() and such, but this is idea.

If you can use the String Class then you would use its iterators to loop through the string.